# I want to change the index of GEP by the result of previous instruction

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm writing a LLVM IR pass that changes the index operand of GetElementPtr instruction at runtime.

I succeeded replacing the GEP index with constant integers. For example,
the code below will replace every last index of GEP instructions with 0.

```cpp
// For each instruction in the function
for(inst_iterator I = inst_begin(F), E = inst_end(F); I != E; ++I){
    // Find GEP instruction
    if(auto *GI = dyn_cast<GetElementPtrInst>(&*I)){
        GI->setOperand(GI->getNumIndices(), ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(I->getContext()), 0));
    }
}
```

the result IR is like this.

```
Original:  %7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %6, i32 0, i32 0
Replace:  %7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %6, i32 0, i32 0
Original:  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %8, i32 0, i32 1
Replace:  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %8, i32 0, i32 0
```

The problem is, when I try to change the index by the result of Instruction on runtime, it fails.
Modified pass:

```cpp
for(inst_iterator I = inst_begin(F), E = inst_end(F); I != E; ++I){
    // Find GEP instruction
    if(auto *GI = dyn_cast<GetElementPtrInst>(&*I)){
        IRBuilder<> Builder(I);
        Instruction* X = Builder.CreateCall(...)
        GI->setOperand(GI->getNumIndices(), X);
    }
}
```

Result of the modified pass:

```
Original:  %7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %6, i32 0, i32 0
Replace:  %7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %6, i32 0, void <badref>
Original:  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %8, i32 0, i32 1
Replace:  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %8, i32 0, void <badref>
GEP indexes must be integers
  %7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %6, i32 0, void <badref>
GEP indexes must be integers
  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %8, i32 0, void <badref>
```

I also tried to get the constant integer value of the returned value by 
`I->setOperand(I->getNumIndices(), ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(I->getContext()), cast<ConstantInt>(X)->getZExtValue()));`
but also doesn't work.

```
Original:  %7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %6, i32 0, i32 0
Replace:  %7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %6, i32 0, i32 784505880
Original:  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %8, i32 0, i32 1
Replace:  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %8, i32 0, i32 784506264
Invalid indices for GEP pointer type!
  %7 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %6, i32 0, i32 784505880
Invalid indices for GEP pointer type!
  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.A, %struct.A* %8, i32 0, i32 784506264
```

I think the reason is that it is impossible to set the GEP index by the runtime results. Then what should I do to change every indices of GEP on runtime?
Do I need to replace the GEP instruction with some address additions and memory access instruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the error message: `GEP indexes must be integers`. If the call is to a function that returns int, then it can work. It doesn't always work — you can call foo() and use the result to get the foo()'th element of an array, but when you're retrieving a struct field, you have to have a constant.

In your second case, you're asking for the 784505880th field of the struct. That's either a bug or an amazingly wide struct ;)

Comment: Yes, it seems the indexes of 'structs' should always be constant integers. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The reason they need to be constant is that the type of a field depends on the index. If you were to change the index at runtime all sorts of assumptions might break.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, using `setOperand()` directly is unsafe. Instead, get a pointer to the operand you want to change and call `GI->replaceUsesOfWith(oldOp, newOp)`.

Comment: replaceUsesOfWith() function replaces every same operand with oldOp by newOp. In my example code, it replaces both i32 0, i32 0 to void <badref> and void <badref>. I should only change the last index.